# Прямая речь внутри авторских слов

Tags: пунктуация

> «Наш друг» страшно обрадовался, одобрительно кивнул мне, словно это
>   была моя личная заслуга, и погрузился в деловые расчеты, выводом из
>   которых не замедлил поделиться: "Россия – это Америка",  –
>   торжественно произнёс он.

Неужто после "поделиться" точку рисовать?.. О_о

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю, что все-таки придется рисовать точку — без прямой речи "объединенное" авторское предложение смысла не имеет.

Сравните:
*Петр Михайлыч хотел сказать: «Не впутывайся ты, пожалуйста, не в свои дела!» — но промолчал* (Ч.).
Без прямой речи: Петр Михайлыч хотел сказать, но промолчал.
[Прямая речь внутри слов автора](http://orthographia.ru/punctum_uk.php?rid=442)

Он уже имел возможность побеседовать с вожаками этого беспримерного похода, составил о них весьма скверное мнение и не замедлил поделиться соображениями со своим зятем.
— Варвары, — со вздохом произнес он, глядя как тысячи оборванцев грузятся на его суда.
[С. В. Шведов. Око Соломона](https://www.litmir.me/br/?b=233858&p=9)

К Греку вдруг пришла мысль, которой он не замедлил поделиться с лейтенантом.
— Слушай, Леха, может, поедем, прокатимся до этой улицы Каляева? — предложил вдруг Грек, и натолкнулся на вопросительный взгляд лейтенанта.
[В. Жуков. Пуля справедливости](https://www.litres.ru/vyacheslav-zhukov/pulya-spravedlivosti/chitat-onlayn/)

Comment: Риммуль, спасибо. Из примеров только второй "наш".

Comment: Всегда рада помочь. (Главное, чтобы толк был.)